# Tooltip not working in web deployed cdf

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, bugs, cdf-format

I deployed a CDF file in a web page. I used both `Mouseover` and `Tooltip` functions. They both work in the raw CDF file. The `Mouseover` function works but the `Tooltip` function does not work in the web deployed version.

Is there something else that has to be done to make this work? or does `Tooltip` just not work on the web-deployed CDFs?

```
projecttext = "Projects are initiated by ...";

project = {Mouseover["Project", {Text[projecttext]} // TableForm]} // 
  TableForm

combineddollarstext = "Combines the values from ...";

combineddollars = {Mouseover["Combined Dollars", 
                   {Text[combineddollarstext]} // TableForm]} //TableForm

measures = FlipView[{"Measures", 
                    {combineddollars, "reportedexpendituredollars", 
                     "grantobligationdata"} //TableForm}]

timeframe = {Tooltip["Year", "Projects are measured within Fiscal Years."]} //TableForm

LayeredGraphPlot[{project -> timeframe, timeframe -> measures, 
     measures -> "Compare", "Compare" -> "Filter"}, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

Comment: It works for me. How did you deploy? (Win7-64, Mathematica v9.01)

Comment: why not show us the web address where the malfunctioning .cdf lives?

Comment: I used Mathematica v9.0.0.0. I deployed it locally on a MAC. I will try to put it up on a site later or tomorrow.

Have not used this forum before and don't see a way to attach a file.

Jeff

Comment: Don't use v9.0.0.0. It is buggy. Update to v9.0.1.0

Comment: Using v9.0.1, Windows, this works just fine for [me](http://test.gluonvision.com/tooltip.html)

Comment: Hi Rolf:
Just upgraded to v9.0.1.0. Recreated the cdf and uploaded to web site. 
http://www.jlapides.com/test/projects.html

Still have a problem. Checked with Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Same problem -- No tooltip function on the Years box. Are you getting a tooltip response for that box?

Jeff

Comment: By the way, what browser were you using?

Once again, I tried on Chrome, Firefox and Safari on a MAC. CDF was generated using MAC version of Mathematica.

Jeff

Answer (score 5):

Wolfram has confirmed that this is a bug. They are working to repair it.

Jeff